# How would I implement a spinning compass dial with numbers that stay vertical?

Tags: swift, drawing, core-animation

I am trying to generate a display for my app that works like the standard iPhone Compass app - specifically, the dial spins, but the annotations (N, S, E, W, and the various numbers) stay vertical as they circle around. I have a version of the app now that works, but I am forced to mix CGAffineTransforms that rotate the dial, and then manually redraw the text into the correct spots. Aside from being silly and wasteful, I don't believe I can use animation with my approach to smooth the rotations. Is there a standard approach to doing this sort of thing? I suppose I could generate a unique affine transform for each number/letter around the ring, but that seems expensive as well. I know it can be done, because the standard compass app is "smooth as butter", as they say. Any ideas?

My app currently has a view that draws the non-textual parts of the dial first. I use CGAffineTransforms to rotate that based on inputs from CLLocation. That works great. I have a second view that manually redraws the all the text portions of the compass dial again based CLLocation heading. I can animate the AffineTransforms, but not the redrawing, so either the updates are out of sync (the dial moves smoothly, while the text is more jittery) or everything is jittery together.

N/A

Would love to have a unified drawing technique that I could animate so my compass animation will be as smooth as the built-in app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  For those who have the same question, it’s a simple solution:

- create your UIView with your rotating dial
- add your text as UILabels, making them subviews of that view
- when you rotate the main view, send it a message to rotate all of its subviews the opposite amount.

Wrap all of that inside an animation, and it will be smooth as silk.

Hope that helps someone...